# How to get object from array on click and send object to component with props?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I started learing Vue.js and I am new in it. So how can get object from array on click? I have a v-for to render my list of users, and next I wanna make is to get the object of user on click and send it to another component with informations of that one clicked user.

My v-for

```
<div v-on:click="doSomethingWith" v-for="user in users">
    <span>
        <div>
            <a>
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    {{ user.picture }}
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span><span><a>{{ user.name }}</a></span></span>
        <span><span><a>{{ user.mobile }}</a></span></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Users component

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      users: [{id: 1, name: 'Joe', mobile: '001001'}, {id: 2, name: 'Sam', mobile: '002002']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doSomethingWith(user) {
        console.log('user', this.user)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

User information component

```
<template>
  <a>{{ user.name }}</a>
  <a>{{ user.mobile }}</a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['user'],
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    console.log('parent_data', this.user)
  }
}
</script>
```

Or can i do this for rendering name and mobile?

```
<a v-model="user.name">
<a v-model="user.mobile">
```

Can anyone help me please? I got stuck on it. Thanks.

Comment: Are the `Users` and `User` components share a common component ancestor? Usually you send an event to the parent and the parent dispatch the event data to the children. BTW, I am also learning Vue

Comment: Users component and User component are divided. I need to import the User component i the Users component right?

Comment: [Non-parent-child communication](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)